# chrome extension opening browser popup window displays blank screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which does the following:
When a user copies a word, a popup window opens with a specific url, searching the word in a dictionary. If the popup window already exists, it removes it and recreates it (if you ask why, the answer is: because `chrome.windows.update()` does not take URL as a parameter so I cannot simply update the window with a new URL).

The problem is: If the user is in another application (like MS Word) and copies a word, when the user clicks on the taskbar icon of the browser (chrome) popup window to bring it on the front, then Chrome does not paint the content of the page, it only displays the title of the page. If the user closes with the X button the popup window though, there is no problem. It happens only if the user just clicks back on MS Word to continue writing and then copies another word, without previously manually closing the popup window. The code is:

```
g_iIntervalID = setInterval(getClipboardText, 500);

function getClipboardText() {
    g_oTA.select(); 
    g_oBG.document.execCommand("Paste");
    var clipText = g_oTA.value;
    if (g_bOpenWindow) {
        clipText = cleanWord(trim(clipText));
        if (clipText != "" && clipText.length <= 64 && clipText != g_sPrevClipText && clipText != g_sWord) {
            if (g_bClipFirstTime == false) {
                g_sWord = clipText;
                openLink();
            }
            g_sPrevClipText = clipText;
        }
        g_bClipFirstTime = false;
    }
}

function openLink() {
    chrome.windows.getAll(onWindowsQueryReply);
}

function onWindowsQueryReply(windows) {
    var bWindowFound = false;

    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
        if (g_iCreatedWindowID != 0 && windows.length > 0) {
            var wnd;
            for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
                wnd = windows[i];
                if (g_iCreatedWindowID == wnd.id) {
                    bWindowFound = true;        
                    var r = chrome.windows.remove(g_iCreatedWindowID, function() {
                        CreateWindow();
                        return;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        if (bWindowFound === false) CreateWindow();
    }
}

function CreateWindow() {
    clearInterval(g_iResizeIntervalID);
    var createData = {
        state: "normal",
        url: "https://www.example.com/search.php?word=" + g_sWord,
        type: "popup",
        top: g_iWinT,
        left: g_iWinL,
        height: g_iWinH,
        width: g_iWinW
    };
    var creating = chrome.windows.create(createData, onWinCreated);
}

function onWinCreated(win) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
        g_iCreatedWindowID = win.id;
        //console.log(g_iWinW + "@" + g_iWinH + "@" + g_iWinT + "@" + g_iWinL + "@@@The panel has been created"+JSON.stringify(win));
        var updateData = {
            state: "normal",
            top: g_iWinT,
            left: g_iWinL,
            drawAttention: true,
            focused: true
        };
        var updating = chrome.windows.update(win.id, updateData);
        g_iResizeIntervalID = setInterval(getWindowSize, 200);
    }
}
```

Steps:

1. User is using an app like MS Word
2. User double clicks a word and ctrl-c or right-click copies it.
3. When this happens then `openLink()` runs
4. The extension removes the current popup window (if it exists) and then creates a new one with a URL
5. A small icon for the new popup window appears flashing in the taskbar
6. The first time, the popup window comes automatically in front. The user reads then necessary information
7. The user clicks back on MS Word to continue work
8. The user marks another word and copies it
9. The extension opens another new popup window. This window for some reason does not come on front like the first time, but this is not the main problem. The user has to click its taskbar icon to bring it in front.
10. The user clicks the icon of the popup window in the taskbar in order to bring it to front.
11. The popup window comes to front, but it displays a blank page (except for the title).
    [image]

Comments:

- Chrome paints the contents ONLY if I click on the title bar and drag the window a bit OR if I hover the mouse on the icon of the pop up window in the taskbar so that a preview is displayed.
- If the user closes the popup window with the X button, then the problem does not arise the next time he copies a word (plus the popup window goes automatically in front/focus, so none of the problems appears).

I have tried many things:

- inserting async delays with setTimeout before creating and updating the pop window
- repositioning and resizing the popup window in `onWinCreated()`
- repositioning and resizing after the first `chrome.windows.update()`

But all these efforts in trying to trigger/force Chrome paint the window, have failed. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this issue? Also, why the first time when the popup opens, it comes automatically in front (or if I closed the previous popup manually)? But when it gets programmatically removed, it does not? Can this also be solved?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, https://crbug.com/1137982, should be fixed in Chrome 98.

Comment: Do you think it will solve both issues? The second issue is that the popup window will come in front ONLY if the previous one was closed manually.

Comment: Try it and if it doesn't, report a new bug.

Comment: updated to chrome 98 and it's not fixed, the initial and most important one bug I mean.